# Набекрень: что такое "бекрень"?

Tags: этимология, лексика

Шапку сдвигают набекрень. Интересно, что изначально означало слово "бекрень", на который шапку сдвигают?

Comment: Ещё здесь слышится "крен" - наклон, сдвиг.

Comment: Очень часто это слово пишут и говорят вот так : накребень)

Comment: Я такого никогда не слышал, но, видимо, здесь ошибка, похожая на "друшлаг" вместо "дуршлаг". Анаграммы из народа.

Answer (score 5):

Этимологические словари, где изучено это слово, объясняют, что это исконно русское.  Сращение предлога "на" и существительного "бекрень" (бок): *носить шапку набекрень*. Известное изречение *мозги набекрень* - разговорное, о том, кто рассуждает или действует неумно, нелепо. 
 По м. Фесмеру трактовка звучит немного занудно, но может что-то для себя полезного Вы и найдете *Обычно сопоставляют с польск. na bakier "вкось, навыворот", укр., блр. на ба́кiр – то же; см. Бернекер 1, 39 и сл.; Mi. EW 6. Польское слово Карлович (25) и Брюкнер (12) объясняют как слово морского жаргона, из нем. Back (Backbord) и kehr' – повел. накл. от kehren "поворачивать"; сходно Маценауэр, LF 7, 5 и Ильинский, РФВ 62, 235. Однако происхождение из немецкого не объясняет отклонения русск. формы. Эта форма не может происходить также и из тюрк., чагат. bögri, bögrü "кривой" (вопреки Маценауэру, там же; против см. Бернекер, там же) или из тур. bekri "пьяница" (Mi. TEI., Доп. 2, 84). Ошибочна также попытка Погодина (РФВ 39, 3) объяснить это слово в качестве исконнослав. из* be-, как в бесе́да и кренить. По сообщенному устно предположению О. Кёлера, бекрень как выражение морского жаргона следует связать с голл. *bekrengen, нем. krengen "склонять в сторону" (Клюге, Seemannsspr.*

Answer (score 1):

**Набекрень.** Искон. Сращение предлога на и сущ. бекрень «бок», в диалектах еще известного (Школьный этимологический словарь русского языка. Происхождение слов. — М.: Дрофа. Н. М. Шанский, Т. А. Боброва. 2004.).

Answer (score 0):

Это слово подробно обсуждается у Мокиенко в "Образах русской речи". Можно посмотреть в интернете, например [здесь](http://www.4tivo.com/other/25331-obrazy-russkojj-rechi.html)